# Как в Unity сделать Collider sphere который из себя не выпускает?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть сфера Collider, как можно сделать, чтобы она из себя не выпускала, то есть когда объект пытался выйти из colliderа происходило столкновенние?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теория: Коллайдер привязывается только к одной стороне мэша. А, значит, сторона как-то выбирается.

Как? Она выбирается по направлению нормалей точек (Vertex Normals). А значит наша задача вывернуть обьект что бы получить идентичные полигоны но с нормалями направленными в другую сторону.

## Вариант 1:

В теории может сработать создание сферы и выставление скейла на -1. В теории это создаст только внутренний коллайдер. Но на практике нужно тебе проверить самому.

Принцип действия: нормали точек должны вывернутся наизнанку вместе со скейлом.

В коментариях Riot пишет что это не сработает с дефолтными примитивами, но сработает с импортированными. Возможно он прав. Но на практике мне проверять влом :D

## Вариант 2:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

public class AddInvertedMeshCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
  public bool removeExistingColliders = true;

  public void CreateInvertedMeshCollider()
  {
    if (removeExistingColliders)
      RemoveExistingColliders();

  InvertMesh();

  gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
  }

  private void RemoveExistingColliders()
  {
    Collider[] colliders = GetComponents<Collider>();
    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
      DestroyImmediate(colliders[i]);
  }

  private void InvertMesh()
  {
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    mesh.triangles = mesh.triangles.Reverse().ToArray();
  }
}
```

А так же:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

[CustomEditor(typeof(AddInvertedMeshCollider))]
public class AddInvertedMeshColliderEditor :Editor
{
  public override void OnInspectorGUI()
  {
    DrawDefaultInspector();
    AddInvertedMeshCollider script = (AddInvertedMeshCollider)target;
    if (GUILayout.Button("Create Inverted Mesh Collider"))
      script.CreateInvertedMeshCollider();
   }
}
```

Код взят отсюда: 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-you-invert-a-sphere-or-box-collider.118733/

Comment: А как это повлияет на коллайдер?

Comment: Это сделает DoubleSide коллайдер. Он будет и извне коллайдить и изнутри.

Comment: Но ведь тут нет ни строчки кода, который меняет меш коллайдера. Разве MeshCollider требует MeshFilter?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Чесно, я с таким не сталкивался и не имел дела с MeshFilter. Я знал лишь в теории как добится результата и просто нагуглил его не проверяя :) 

Понятия не имею как работает этот код и что он конкретно делает на практике. А как это действует в теории я расписал в апдейте моего ответа.

Comment: Просто там даже в комментарии к оригинальному ответу написали, что это никак не повлияет на меш коллайдера. В общем, тут стоит уточнить, что MeshCollider использует меш, предоставляемый MeshFilter'ом.

Comment: окей, есть еще вариант)

Comment: Но вообще способ крутой, давно не видел использование clockwise/counter-clockwise индексации полигонов.

Comment: Второй способ будет работать только при импорте меши, в рантайме скейл не выставить.

Comment: я заапдейтил ответ убрав первый вариант и добавив еще один новый)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker что б ты понимал, я ж вообще не юнитист... Да и не програмер вообще... Я ленивое безработное чмо :D А то что мы с тобой пересекаемся здесь постоянно на тэге юнити... Это просто хобби у меня такое... херней страдать и людям помогать :D Я даже не помню когда я юнити запускал в последний раз нормально.

Comment: Да ладно, я тоже не работаю сейчас, а знания - вещь довольно субъективная, так что не нужно себя принижать :)

Comment: Та то я любя :D